# Load entire SQLite database into RAM to improve performance

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a large SQLite database for my application (around 100MB). This database is read only and never written into. The performance of working with the database is decent, since I made sure that most of the queries have indexes backing them up. However I would like to speed it up further by caching the entire database into RAM to avoid disk access.

Is this possible and if so how can I do it?

Comment: You are certainly welcome to read all your database contents into POJOs, but you will not have enough heap space on many, if not most, Android devices.

Comment: I simply want to cache the raw database into RAM so that instead of making query to a database on disk the query will be made to a database in RAM. That's my intention.

Comment: You're likely to make your app crash. Be aware that your device doesn't have an HDD, so it's not subject to mechanical slow downs. Therefore this supposed enhancement is not only useless, but most likely harmful.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point with HDD is. Even the fastest flash storage on Android can't beat RAM in speed.

Comment: You are certainly welcome to try [creating a memory-backed database](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#create(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)) and load the entire contents of your on-disk database into it. I do not know how SQLite memory-backed databases relate to your process' heap limit. Also, loading 100MB of data from disk will take quite some time.

Comment: "Even the fastest flash storage on Android can't beat RAM in speed" -- correct, but reading 100MB of data from flash storage will be slower than reading less than 100MB of data from flash storage. And, a lot of time up front is usually considered worse from a UX standpoint than little bits of time spread out. So, the key (besides whether you will run out of memory) is whether your average user will be doing so much work with your app to make it worth the up-front cost of this massive data load.

Answer (score 1):

A database file is a file, so you can just read it to put it into the OS's file cache. (And if the OS decides to throw the data out again, then it might have a reason for it …)

For an on-disk database, SQLite needs to check if some other process has made changes. To avoid that, you can use 
[PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode). However, the difference probably isn't measurable.